# CriteriaBulder in recursive related DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with a recursive relationship and I'm trying to find all records that matched the "name" field at 2 levels: root and parent:

```
@Entity
public class NvCoinCategoryDict implements Persistence {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private NvCategory category;
}


@Entity
public class NvCategory implements Persistence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private NvCategory parent;
}
```

For this I create two predicates

```
 (root, criteriaQuery, builder) -> {
                        final ListJoin<CatCoin, NvCoinCategoryDict> categoryDicts = root.joinList("categoryDicts", JoinType.LEFT);
                        final Predicate inParent = categoryDicts.get("category").get("parent").get("name").in(filter.getCategory());
                        final Predicate inRoot = categoryDicts.get("category").get("name").in(filter.getCategory());
                        return builder.or(inParent, inRoot);
```

Each predicate on its own handles the search as it should, but in the OR pair, the search occurs only at the parent level. Why is this happening and can it be fixed?

Comment: "but in the OR pair, the search occurs only at the parent level" - but how did you come to this conclusion? Your question is lacking the dataset you were trying this with and the query logging that shows your findings.

Comment: Do you mean the joins between categoryDicts, category and parent are created independently for the two clauses? If you want the *or* clause to function on the same category, you should reuse the same expression in building the clauses. Calling get multiple times creates a new expression and so a new join each time.